# Efficient of Newton Polynomial Evaluation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, numerical-methods

The polynomial in Newton form having the coefficients $a_{0},a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}$ and centers $x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ is the polynomial 
$$ p(x) = a_{0} + a_{1} (x-x_{1}) +a_{2} (x-x_{1})(x-x_{2}) + \cdots + a_{n} (x-x_{1})\cdots (x-x_{n}). $$
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and set 
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
b_{n} &= a_{n}, \\
b_{i} & = a_{i} + b_{i+1} ( \alpha - x_{i+1}), \; \text{for } i=n-1,n-2,\ldots,0.
\end{array} \right.
$$
Then $b_{0} = p(\alpha)$. This is the generalized Horner's rule for evaluating Polynomial in Newton form. This algorithm takes at most 2n additions and n mutiplications. I am trying to prove that in the case $x_{i} \neq x_{j}, i \neq j$ and all the coeficients $a_{i}$ is nonzero and $\alpha \neq x_{i}$ for all $i$, this algorithm is optimal. I think that we may need to generalize the proof of Alexander Ostrowski in 1954 for Horner's rule (he proved that the number of additions required in evaluating arbitrary polynomial must be at least n, the degree of that polynomial), but I am struggling to do it.

So my question is: Is this algorithm optimal in the case above?.

Any help would be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: Seems unlikely.  Consider $\frac{x^4-1}{x-1} = x^3+x^2+x+1$, best evaluated as $\frac{(x^2)^2-1}{x-1}$, with two multiplications, two additions, and one division.  Or as $(x^2+1)(x+1)$ ...

Comment: Heck, even the most efficient way to compute the power of $x$ in a monomial isn't straightforward.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring versus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation, for instance.