# Algorithm for Finding Coefficients of Newton Basis Polynomials ($n_k(x) = \prod_{j = 0}^{k -1}(x - x_j)$)

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

I am trying to do polynomial interpolation algorithmically with Newton's divided differences. I am able to find the divided differences $f[x_0, x_1, ... , x_n]$ okay, but I am struggling to find the coefficients of the Newton basis polynomial algorithmically:

$$
n_k(x) = \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(x - x_j)
$$

Where the first few are:
$$
n_1(x) = x - x_0
$$
$$
n_2(x) = x^2 - (x_0 + x_1)x + x_0x_1 
$$
$$
n_3(x) = x^3 - (x_0 + x_1 + x_2)x^2 + (x_0x_1 + x_0x_2 + x_1x_2)x - x_0x_1x_2
$$

The final resulting coefficients that I'm interested in are just of course the linear combination of the coefficients from the basis polynomials $a_k$ with the divided differences.

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}(a_k \cdot f[x_0, ... , x_i])
$$

What is the most efficient way to calculate $a_k$ (coefficients of $n_k(x)$) given all $x_j$?

Comment: Why do you need these coefficients explicitely (they are not needed to evaluate the interpolation polynomial) ?

Comment: In fact you first need a algorithm to find all subsets of size $1,2,\dots,n+1 $of $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet My goal is to calculate an interpolating polynomial given a set of data, and then use the resulting interpolation polynomial as a function in another application. Do I not need these $a_k$ to get the resulting polynomial in standard form or in the form for Horner's evaluation method?

Comment: Since you are able to compute the coefficients in the Newton basis you just need to provided these coefficients and the $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}$ and use Horner no ?

Comment: I'm able to compute the divided differences $f[x_0,...x_n]$ but not the newton basis coefficients $a_k$ yet, but yes, once I'm able to compute the $a_k$ then I can use Horner.

Comment: Horner can work with the Newton coefficients and in the Newton basis. You don't need the coefficients in the canonical basis $\{1,x,\dots x^n\}$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462843/efficient-of-newton-polynomial-evaluation